# Snowpipe vs Airflow for Continues data loading into Snowflake

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, snowflake-pipe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I had a question related to Snowflake. Actually in my current role, I am planning to migrate data from ADLS (Azure data lake) to Snowflake.
I am right now looking for 2 options

1. Creating Snowpipe to load updated data
2. Create Airflow job for same.

I am still trying to understand which will be the best way and what is the pro and cons of choosing each.

Comment: Is it much more preferable to schedule the copy of data from ADLS to Snowflake via Airflow job? I know there is an Airflow Snowflake CLI connector. The issue is that the jobs will need to be in sync. Airflow also helps with dependency management and a notification system. How would you propose doing all the things we do in Airflow in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to as part of this migration. If it is a plain vanilla(no transformation, no complex validations) as-is migration of data from ADLS to Snowflake, then you may be good with SnowPipe(but please also check if your scenario is good for Snowpipe or Bulk Copy- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html#recommended-load-file-size).

If you have many steps before you move the data to snowflake and there are chances that you may need to change your workflow in future, it is better to use Airflow which will give you more flexibility. In one of my migrations, I used Airflow and in the other one CONTROL-M

Comment: Isn't Airflow should be compared with Snowflake Task not with Snowpipe.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to load higher volumes of data with lower latency if you use Snowpipe instead of Airflow. It'll also be easier to manage Snowpipe in my opinion.

Airflow is a batch scheduler and using it to schedule anything that runs more frequently than 5 minutes becomes painful to manage. Also, you'll have to manage the scaling yourself with Airflow. Snowpipe is a serverless option that can scale up and down based on the volumes sees and you're going to see your data land within 2 minutes.

The only thing that should restrict your usage of Snowpipe is cost. Although, you may find that Snowpipe ends up being cheaper in the long run if you consider that you'll need someone to manage your Airflow pipelines too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few considerations. Snowpipe can only run a single copy command, which has some limitations itself, and snowpipe imposes further limitations as per [Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-pipe.html#usage-notes). The main pain is that it does not support `PURGE = TRUE | FALSE (i.e. automatic purging while loading)` saying:

> Note that you can manually remove files from an internal (i.e.
> Snowflake) stage (after they’ve been loaded) using the REMOVE command.

Regrettably the snowflake docs are famously vague as they use an ambiguous colloquial writing style. While it said you 'can' remove the files manually yourself in reality any user using snowpipe as advertised for "continuous fast ingestion" *must* remove the files to not suffer performance/cost impacts of the copy command having to ignore a very large number of files that have been previously loaded. The docs around the cost and performance of "table directories" which are implicit to stages talk about 1m files being a lot of files. By way of an official example the [default pipe flush time](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#optional-properties) on snowflake kafka connector snowpipe is 120s so assuming data ingests continually, and you make one file per flush, you will hit 1m files in 2 years. Yet using snowpipe is supposed to imply low latency. If you were to lower the flush to 30s you may hit the 1m file mark in about half a year.

If you want a fully automated process with no manual intervention this could mean that after you have pushed files into a stage and invoked the pipe you need logic have to poll the API to learn which files were eventually loaded. Your logic can then remove the loaded files. The official snowpipe Java example code has some logic that pushes files then polls the API to check when the files are eventually loaded. The snowflake kafka connector also polls to check which files the pipe has eventually asynchronously completed. Alternatively, you might write an airflow job to `ls @the_stage` and look for files `last_modified` that is in the past greater than some safe threshold to then `rm @the_stage/path/file.gz` the older files.

The next limitation is that a copy command is a "copy into your_table" command that can only target a single table. You can however do advanced transformations using SQL in the copy command.

Another thing to consider is that neither latency nor throughput is guaranteed with snowpipe. The documentation very clearly says you should measure the latency yourself. It would be a completely "free lunch" if snowpipe that is running on shared infrastructure to reduce your costs were to run instantly and as fast if you were paying for hot warehouses. It is reasonable to assume a higher tail latency when using shared "on-demand" infrastructure (i.e. a low percentage of invocations that have a high delay).

You have no control over the size of the warehouse used by snowpipe. This will affect the performance of any sql transforms used in the copy command. In contrast if you run on Airflow you have to assign a warehouse to run the copy command and you can assign as big a warehouse as you need to run your transforms.

A final consideration is that to use snowpipe you need to make a Snowflake API call. That is significantly more complex code to write than making a regular database connection to load data into a stage. For example, the regular Snowflake JDBC database connection has advanced methods to make it efficient to [stream data into stages](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) without having to write `oAuth` code to call the snowflake API.

Be very clear that if you carefully read the [snowpipe documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-pipe.html) you will see that snowpipe is simply a restricted [copy into table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) command running on shared infrastructure that is eventually run at some point; yet you yourself can run a full copy command as part of a more complex SQL script on a warehouse that you can size and suspend. If you can live with the restrictions of snowpipe, can figure out how to remove the files in the stage yourself, and you can live with the fact that tail latency and throughput is likely to be higher than paying for a dedicated warehouse, then it could be a good fit.